# VS2012 MVC 4.0 Intranet Project using WebMatrix.WebData Reference fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership, webmatrix-2

I did the following:

Create in VS 2012 a MVC 4.0 Application with the Intranet template, switch WindowsAuthentication on.
Project can be started and shows Home page.

Then I added under References WebMatrix.WebData and set Copy Local true.

Starting the Application then returns a 404 Error indicating Requested Url: /login.aspx

Strange, isn't it?

I would like to use SimpleMembership Provider but if I cannot even reference the DLL this doesnt convince me.

Can anyone help me up?

Answer (score 1):

MVC4 Intranet Project template provides a web.config with:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

For some reason unknown to me, just adding the Microsoft ASP.Net Web Pages 2 Nuget Package to a Web App generated from MVC 4 Intranet Project template changes the routing behaviour of the whole application such that /login.aspx becomes the default routing when no controller/action is specified.

This is the defaultUrl default value defined for forms authentication,
see [forms-Element definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for details.

The following two bypasses work:

1. Change Route Map by adding something like

   ```
       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "LoginRedirect",
           url: "login.aspx/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
   ```

   into Route table.
2. Modify web.config to contain

   ```
   <authentication mode="Windows">
     <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Index" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index"/>
   </authentication>
   ```

where the forms element provides the proper start page.

Either works. The latter seems more agreeable to me.